# how I can get rid of null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> 'here is login form page'

```
<form action="login">
    Enter user:<input type="text" value="user">
    Enter pass:<input type="password" value="pass">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
        
</form>
```

> 'here is login servlet class code'

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String uname = request.getParameter("user");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    if (user.equals("Navin") && pass.equals("navin")) {
            response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: set the id's of the fields in your form  to `user` and `pass`

Comment: You should  add name attributes to your user and pass input tags.   <input type="text" value="user" name="user"> <input type="password" value="pass" name="pass">